# SSAS Internal error: An Unexpected error occurred (file 'pfcre.cpp' function PFCREngine::SelectCartridge)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssas, data-warehouse, cube

Has anyone seen this error before? If so, how did you fix it? I can't find anything on Google.

Here is what I have done:

1. I tried doing a Google search but practically nothing came up.
2. I checked all of my permissions everywhere, and from what I can tell, that is not the problem.
3. Building and deploying does not generate errors.
4. I only have errors when I try to process my cube.

**Edit #1:**

I have attached an image showing version information. I have never successfully processed a cube. I have been getting this from the very beginning of when I tried to process one.

[image: version informations]

**Edit #2**

Sorry for the delay, but I ran into some errors thanks to Windows latest update.

I am no longer receiving this error message after reinstalling everything, but this is what I have now:

[image: WIDE World Importers DW database I downloaded somewhere from Microsoft I believe]

I am trying to teach myself how to use SSAS for self-learning. I downloaded the database somewhere from Microsoft.

[image: privileges]

Comment: Is this the only error or there are some addition ones related to engine ?

Comment: When this error started to appear?  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @tukan I attached an image showing my version information.

Comment: @DanielHanczyc I am processing it right now to get all of the error information. I have not tried in a while, I will edit my post shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ran into another error thanks to Windows latest update. I am currently trying to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Try using the same SQL Server Management studio **version** as you have **SSAS**.  There maybe incompatibilities when using newer versions.

Comment: Will do, I'm going to have to uninstall anyway as I'm getting a completely new error message now

Comment: Wait, wasn't that the same version that I posted above? I'm not sure why it says 18.1 at the top and 15.xxx below that though.

Comment: Please use at (@ with the nick) otherwise I'll not get your message.  The reason why you are getting different versions is that your server is different version than your client.

Comment: @DanielHanczyc


I have edited my post. After reinstalling everything due to receiving errors thanks to Windows latest updates, I am no longer getting this error, but now I am running into the ones in my 2nd edit.

Comment: @tukan I can only tag 1 person per post, so that last post was meant for you as well.

Comment: Well that is completely different issue than the topic.  this is probably because you don't have the user created in your user/password. If you have downloaded somewhere from M$ than you need to check what was written with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio as well as SQL Server due to an update that was causing errors.

After doing so, I was no longer able to reproduce the error message in part #1; however, part #2, `Login failed for user NT Service \MSSQLServerOLAPService.;28000`,  was resolved by doing the following:

1. Logging into SQL Server Management Studio
2. Creating a new login for  `NT Service \MSSQLServerOLAPService`.
3. Assigning the `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` role
   memberships.

After following these steps, I did not have any trouble processing my cube.

If I am able regenerate error #1 again, I will add more detail to my post, otherwise, I am problem free for the time being.